# How to pass parameter value in DynamicJasper 5.0.0+

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

My question is about a specific situation. Current project is with DynamicJasper 5.0.0. It create a main dynamic report with many subreports concatenate one after another, and each subreport also take an existing jrxml template:

```
String jrxmlTemplateFile = "META-INF/jasperReports/single_subreport.jrxml";
subBuilder.setTemplateFile(jrxmlTemplateFile, false, false, true, false);
```

I set the 4th parameter to true because there are parameters defined in the single_subreport.jrxml, and I really like to pass the value from java.

```
subReport.addParameter(name, className);
```

can add parameter into the dynamic report but don't know how to pass the parameter, and where can set the position of the parameter.

So I really appreciate if there is any way to restore the usage like

```
report.setParameters(..)
```

so I can pass any value I want to the existing jrxml template.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have u define the parameters in `single_subreport.jrxml`? something like `<parameter name="ReportTitle" class="java.lang.String"/>`. That will allow you to pass the parameter value from java.

Comment: Registering a parameter is needed if later in your template you want to reference it by name, but you can have dynamic params by referencing the $P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("your key") y your expressions (and casting properly, etc, etc)